# Find the points on the curve $x^4+y^4+3xy=2$ closest and farthest to the origin

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, maxima-minima, lagrange-multiplier

I need to find the points on the curve $x^4+y^4+3xy=2$ that are closest and farthest to the origin.

I believe this might be a Lagrange multiplier problem, but I am not sure. I was thinking that maybe minimizing/maximizing the function would be the way to go.

Comment: You are talking about minimizing/maximizing *which* function?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos The function that is the distance of a point on the curve to the origin, i.e. $x^2+y^2$.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel I know that that's the way to go. But I was trying to see whether the OP knew that. Of course, now, thanks to your comment, we will never know, right?!

Comment: Yes, this is a Lagrange multiplier problem. Try it.

Comment: Wouldn't the distance from a point on the curve to the origin be sqrt(x^2+y^2) instead of x^2 + y^2 using the distance formula?

Comment: @user604720 You can maximise/minimise $x^2+y^2$ first, then take square root :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I saw people recommending to use lagrange multiplier, but I know none of that. Instead, I tried this.

Firstly, you want to maximise/minimise (sqrt) $x^2+y^2$ with $x^4+y^4+3xy-2=0$. Consider $x^2+y^2=t$ and the intersection point $(u, v)$. i.e.

$$u^2+v^2=t, u^4+v^4+3uv-2=0$$

If at the point $(u, v)$, we can get both of the $\frac{dy}{dx}$ to be equal, then it means the curve $x^2+y^2-t=0$ and $x^4+y^4+3xy-2=0$ are tangent to each other.[image]

**Finding $\frac{dy}{dx}$ of both functions**

Implicit differentiation gives

$$x^2+y^2=t \implies \frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{x}{y}$$

$$x^4+y^4+3xy-2=0 \implies \frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{4x^3+3y}{4y^3+3x}$$

**We want to equal those. After simplifying**

$$4xy^3+3x^2=4x^3y+3y^2$$

$$3(x^2-y^2)=4xy(x^2-y^2)$$

$$xy=\frac{3}{4} \textrm{ or } x=\pm y$$

If $xy=\frac{3}{4}$, $x^4+y^4+3(\frac{3}{4})-2=0 \implies x^4+y^4=-\frac{1}{4}$ which is impossible since LHS is non-negative.

Therefore, $x=\pm y$

**If ** $x=y$, $2x^4+3x^2-2=0\implies(2x^2-1)(x^2+2)=0\implies x=\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, y=\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, \sqrt{x^2+y^2}=1$

**If ** $x=-y$, $2x^4-3x^2-2=0\implies(2x^2+1)(x^2-2)=0\implies x=\pm \sqrt{2}, y=\mp \sqrt{2}, \sqrt{x^2+y^2}=2$

$$\therefore 1<\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<2$$
<s>Side note: To the people doing lagrange multiplier, stop and calm down :)</s> As mentioned in the comments, (apparently) this is the foundation of lagrange multiplier - Langrange multiplier is basically a generalisation of this to any constraint-equations and more variables :)

Comment: +1 Damn, beat me to it! Same approach, just you were quicker.

Comment: muahahahaha >:)

Comment: The Lagrange multipliers directly lead to your equation "After simplifying". The rest of the discussion is the same.

Comment: Just pointing out that in the case of a single constraint in two variables this method (shared tangents) *is* essentially the method of Lagrange multipliers. At least that's the way it is whenever I teach vector calculus :-)

Comment: :O I see... That's interesting haha. How I thought of this was I plotted the two equations on desmos with a slider for $t$, then I realised when they are tangent to each other there'll be a maximum/minimum. Then it's tangent and standard stuff haha

Comment: I rather think of it as follows: This method explains why Lagrange multipliers work. Basically we are using Implicit Function theorem to convert this to a usual *find the zeros of the derivative*

Answer (score 2):

By Lagrange, we minimize

$$x^2+y^2+\lambda(x^4+y^4+3xy-2).$$

The derivatives on $x$ and $y$ yield

$$2x+\lambda(4x^3+3y)=2y+\lambda(4y^3+3x)=0,$$ and after elimination of $\lambda$,

$$2x(4y^3+3x)=2y(4x^3+3y)$$ or

$$(8xy-6)(y^2-x^2)=0.$$

The solutions $y=\pm x$ imply

$$2x^4\pm3x^2-2=0,$$ giving

$$x^2+y^2=2x^2=\frac{\mp3\pm5}2$$ and only the positive solutions $1$ and $4$ are valid.

Next, with $xy=\dfrac34$,

$$x^4+y^4+3xy-2=(x^2+y^2)^2-2x^2y^2+3xy-2=(x^2+y^2)^2-\frac98+\frac94-2=0$$

and

$$x^2+y^2=\sqrt{\frac78}.$$

Anyway, we would have $(x-y)^2=x^2+y^2-2xy<0$, which is not possible.

Final answers: the solution points are $\pm\left(\dfrac1{\sqrt2},\dfrac1{\sqrt2}\right)$ and $\pm(\sqrt2,-\sqrt2).$

Answer (score 1):

You've already got adequate answers, but this is just another way to do it -- especially fitted for this particular curve, as we'll find out.

The problem, reformulated, is to find the smallest circle intersecting the curve so that no point on the curve lies within the circle; on the other hand we need the largest circle intersecting the curve so that no point on the curve lies outside it.

1. To find this least circle, let its radius be $r.$ Then we seek the least such $r$ satisfying the equations $x^2+y^2=r^2$ and $x^4+y^4+3xy=2.$ Squaring the first and substituting gives $$2-3xy+2(xy)^2=r^4,$$ a quadratic in $xy.$ Thus we easily find that the minimum value of $r^4,$ occurring at $xy=3/4,$ is given by $r^4=7/8.$ Hence our points lie on $xy=3/4$ and $x^2+y^2=\sqrt{7/8}.$ Thus we find that $x^2$ and $y^2$ are the roots of the quadratic $$m^2-\sqrt{7/8}m+9/16=0.$$ From here I believe you may proceed.
2. To find the largest circle, we instead use the complementary circle of the hyperbola $x^2-y^2=s^2,$ whose vertices define the circle. Hence the radius of this circle is $s.$ Proceeding as above, we obtain that $$2-3xy-2(xy)^2=s^4,$$ which gives the maximum of $s^4$ as $25/8,$ occurring when $xy=-3/4.$ Thus our farthest points lie on the curves $xy=-3/4$ and $x^2-y^2=5/\sqrt 8.$ To solve this note that $(x^2+y^2)^2-(x^2-y^2)^2=4(xy)^2,$ which gives us that $x^2+y^2=\sqrt{43/8}.$ Hence $x^2$ and $y^2$ are the roots of the quadratic $$n^2-\sqrt{43/8}n+9/16=0,$$ from where you may proceed.

Comment: Notice for the first case the determinant is <0 so there’s no solution

Comment: @GarethMa Hmm, that's very curious. What could have gone wrong?

Comment: In fact nothing, since there’s just... no solution to the equation

Comment: @GarethMa But there's got to be some point on the curve closest to the origin, no?

Comment: Wait let me think about it. But I know the answer should be 1, given by $(\frac{1}{sqrt{2}},-\frac{1}{sqrt{2}})$.

Comment: I see why now. Take a look at the line "minimum of $r^4$, occuring at $xy=3/4$". If this is true, in the constraint, $x^4+y^4=-1/4$ which... clear to see why it's bad >:). However to fix this, you cannot simply let $xy=\frac{2}{3}$ yet. Let me think (again) lmao

Answer (score 0):

We'll prove that $\max(x^2+y^2)=4.$

Indeed, let $xy\geq0$.

Thus, by C-S $$2=x^4+y^4+3xy\geq x^4+y^4=\frac{(1+1)(x^4+y^4)}{2}\geq\frac{(x^2+y^2)^2}{2},$$
which gives $$x^2+y^2\leq2<4.$$
Now, let $xy\leq0.$

Thus, by C-S again and AM-GM we obtain:
$$2=x^4+y^4+3xy\geq\frac{(x^2+y^2)^2}{2}-\frac{3(x^2+y^2)}{2},$$
which gives $$(x^2+y^2)^2-3(x^2+y^2)-4\leq0$$ or
$$(x^2+y^2-4)(x^2+y^2+1)\leq0$$ or
$$x^2+y^2\leq4.$$
The equality occurs for $(x^2,y^2)||(1,1)$ and $x=-y,$ which with our condition gives:
$$(x,y)=(\sqrt2,-\sqrt2)$$ or
$$(x,y)=(-\sqrt2,\sqrt2).$$
By the similar way we can prove that $\min(x^2+y^2)=1,$ where the equality occurs for $$(x,y)=\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt2},\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\right)$$ or 
$$(x,y)=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt2},-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\right).$$